# JsForce(nodejs) for the Oauth, its not returning RefreshToken

Tags: oauth2, node.js

Using JSForce(nodejs), I create a new connection were it will returns accesstoken,Instance_URL and refreshToken and Userdetails. The thing is it returns accesstoken, Instance_URL and Userdetails but not returning refreshToken. can any one please help me solving this.

```
app.get('/oauth2/callback', function(req, res) {
   var conn = new sf.Connection({ oauth2 : oauth2 });
   var code = req.param('code');
   conn.authorize(code, function(err, userInfo) {
   if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    // Now you can get the access token, refresh token, and instance URL    Blockquoteinformation.
   // Save them to establish connection next time.
      console.log(conn.accessToken);
      console.log(conn.refreshToken);
      console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
      console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
      console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
   // ...
});   });
```

Comment: Did you ever find out why you weren't receiving a refreshToken? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Lee Harrison, No I'm still facing the same problem, but Please check whether you included "refresh token" scope in your Connected App setting. 
Have a look here for more details. https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/163. In case you solved this issue let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by including "refresh token" scope in the Connected App setting. and also by replacing the following code.

res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({scope: 'api id web'}));
to
res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({ scope: 'api id web refresh_token' }));
or
res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl());

Click here for more details. https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/242